# How can I write CSS selector(s) that apply to table rows for all td elements on that row after a td with a certain class?

Tags: css, html-table, css-selectors

In a table, I'm trying to place top borders on and after a cell with a particular class and bottom borders before a cell with a particular class, so borders across the row, top after the class and bottom before the class. Is that doable with CSS selectors, or do I have to solve it with JavaScript? I know the tr element is a container element and thus in most browsers border is ignored. The class is dynamically added to the cell with JavaScript.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.a {
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
  border-top: 2px solid gray;
}

.a td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
}

.a tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 2px solid gray;
}

.a tr:not(:first-child) td {
  border-top: 2px solid gray;
}

.a td:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid gray;
}

.a tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="b">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="a">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="b">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit:

Adding image of desired output.

[image: css-borders]

Comment: `.a td` and `.a tr` are descendant selectors. Please review the basics of CSS to fix that.

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to understand your goals. You say "on or after". What does "after" mean? On the following cell? You also mention rows, so I'm confused. Please revise to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targeting modern browsers, you [can use](https://caniuse.com/css-has) the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class to target the rows which have a cell with that class. Then, target all of the cells in that row (except the one with that class) and give them the bottom border. Finally, use the [`~` general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) to target all of the cells after the one with the class and give those a top border and remove (or in this case, hide) the bottom border.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.a {
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
  border-top: 2px solid gray;
}

tr:has(.a) td:not(.a) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}

tr:has(.a) td.a ~ td {
  border-top: 2px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="b">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="a">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="b">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, I don't need to worry about older browsers. This css does not seem to work. With this css, if I add class="a" to the TR element I get a top border across the entire row, but otherwise no border.

Comment: Right, you said you were adding the class to a cell, not a row. Your example shows the "a" class on a cell as well. It doesn't make any sense to add it on a row: how would it know what cell to shift from top to bottom?

Comment: Right, I was just saying that the css as-is does not work when I run the code snippet, but adding the class to the tr element did produce a border, just not the bottom border before the cell class, and top border after the cell class.

Comment: The CSS works in the code snippet, and does exactly what you asked it to do; namely, adds a bottom border on all of the cells before the cell with the class applied and a top border to all of the cells after the cell with the class applied. The output of the snippet matches exactly the "desired output" in the question. Placing the class anywhere else, like on a row, table, or any other element except a `td` with a parent `tr`, will not produce the desired effect.

Comment: It does not like Firefox for some reason, but it works with Chrome! ty

Comment: :has() is not supported by Firefox at present.

Comment: Updated question with link to https://caniuse.com/css-has which has up-to-date information on browser support.